# Strange result with my array inside a while loop in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I would like to fill a simply array in bash inside a while loop.

I try to do this :

```
read -p " Value : " nb

declare -a array

while [[ $nb != "s" ]]
do
    read -p " Value : " nb
    array+=("$nb")
done

echo ${array[@]}
```

If I try with 1,2,3,4 and 5 as values, the output is :

```
Value : 1
Value : 2
Value : 3
Value : 4
Value : 5 ( to stop the loop and display the array )
2 3 4 5 s
```

Or, I wan this output :

```
Value : 1
Value : 2
Value : 3
Value : 4
Value : 5
Value : s 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Can you tell me what is wrong in my script ?

Comment: Your code does a `read`, then it does an append, and *then* it goes up to to do the test to decide if it should run the loop again. Thus, the append happens whether or not that test would succeed.

Comment: There's nothing at all bash-specific about this -- you'd have the exact same behavior with C's `while` loop, or Python's, or Java's, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines of code inside your while loop need to be swapped.

```
read -p " Value : " nb

declare -a array

while [[ $nb != "s" ]] do
    array+=("$nb")
    read -p " Value : " nb
done
echo ${array[@]}
```

Now your first read is put into your array and your last read (to exit the loop) is not put into the array.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest quoting `"${array[@]}"`; that way a `*` won't be replaced with a list of filenames. You might also use the `-r` argument to `read` so backslashes don't get munged.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `read` is not adding the input to your array. So just keep your `read` inside the while loop. Then only add the input to the array if it does not equal `s`.

```
declare -a array

while [[ $nb != "s" ]]; do 
  read -p "Value: " nb
  if [[ $nb != "s" ]]; then 
    array+=($nb)
  fi 
done 

echo ${array[@]}
```

---

**Update:** terser syntax, thanks to comment by Charles Duffy.

```
declare -a array

while :; do 
  read -p "Value: " nb
  [[ $nb == s ]] && break
  array+=($nb)
done 

echo ${array[@]}
```

Comment: Why have the first test at all? Just put `[[ $nb = s ]] && break` after the `read`, and change `while [[ $nb != "s" ]]; do` to `while :; do`; then you can get rid of the `if`.